# Helm repo to install istio

Tags: kubernetes-helm, istio

I am trying to install istio. I can easily package the helm chart if I clone the repo from github but I am just wondering if there is a helm chart repo that I can use?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a way to install istio version higher than 1.8.0 then there is a good news.

According to [documentation](https://istio.io/latest/news/releases/1.8.x/announcing-1.8/) helm support is back, currently in alpha.

> We’ve added support for installing Istio with Helm 3. This includes both in-place upgrades and canary deployment of new control planes, after installing 1.8 or later. Helm 3 support is currently Alpha, so please try it out and give your feedback.

---

There is istio [documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/helm/) about installing Istio with Helm 3, Helm 2 is not supported for installing Istio.

There are the Prerequisites:

- [Download the Istio release](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/getting-started/#download)
- [Perform any necessary platform-specific setup](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/platform-setup/)
- [Check the Requirements for Pods and Services](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/deployment/requirements/)
- [Install a Helm client with a version higher than 3.1.1](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/install/)

There are the installation steps for istio 1.8.1:

> Note that the default chart configuration uses the secure third party tokens for the service account token projections used by Istio proxies to authenticate with the Istio control plane. Before proceeding to install any of the charts below, you should **verify if third party tokens are enabled in your cluster** by following the steps describe [here](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/best-practices/security/#configure-third-party-service-account-tokens). **If third party tokens are not enabled, you should add the option --set global.jwtPolicy=first-party-jwt** to the Helm install commands. If the jwtPolicy is not set correctly, pods associated with istiod, gateways or workloads with injected Envoy proxies will not get deployed due to the missing istio-token volume.

1.Download the Istio release and change directory to the root of the release package and then follow the instructions below.

```
curl -L https://istio.io/downloadIstio | ISTIO_VERSION=1.8.1 sh -
cd istio-1.8.1
```

2.Create a namespace istio-system for Istio components:

```
kubectl create namespace istio-system
```

3.Install the Istio base chart which contains cluster-wide resources used by the Istio control plane:

```
helm install -n istio-system istio-base manifests/charts/base
```

4.Install the Istio discovery chart which deploys the istiod service:

```
helm install --namespace istio-system istiod manifests/charts/istio-control/istio-discovery \
    --set global.hub="docker.io/istio" --set global.tag="1.8.1"
```

5.Install the Istio ingress gateway chart which contains the ingress gateway components:

```
helm install --namespace istio-system istio-ingress manifests/charts/gateways/istio-ingress \
    --set global.hub="docker.io/istio" --set global.tag="1.8.1"
```

6.(Optional) Install the Istio egress gateway chart which contains the egress gateway components:

```
helm install --namespace istio-system istio-egress manifests/charts/gateways/istio-egress \
    --set global.hub="docker.io/istio" --set global.tag="1.8.1"
```

7.Verify that all Kubernetes pods in istio-system namespace are deployed and have a STATUS of Running:

```
kubectl get pods -n istio-system
```

Comment: My mistake was installing Istio locally and thinking it was just a CLI tool at first and went to a different directory and attempted to install Istio. Don't be like me and not notice that the helm install refers to a manifest IN the Istio install.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. A quick google search turned this up: https://github.com/istio/istio/tree/master/install/kubernetes/helm/istio

Comment: when I just checked this link returned a 404

Comment: Yes , it's 404 for me, can you please update the correct link

Comment: This post is over three years old. Of course it doesn't work. If you would like to hunt down the link I would be happy to update this.

Answer (score 0):

It's a pain to find, and they don't really reference it properly in the documentation, but according to [these](https://github.com/istio/istio.io/pull/2842#issue-228469747) [two](https://github.com/istio/istio.io/pull/2842#issuecomment-436137840) comments, the charts can be found in the following locations:

- master: https://gcsweb.istio.io/gcs/istio-prerelease/daily-build/master-latest-daily/charts/
- v1.1.x: https://gcsweb.istio.io/gcs/istio-prerelease/daily-build/release-1.1-latest-daily/charts/

Answer (score 0):

For a more recent answer, you can now add helm repository for istio for a specific version with `helm repo add istio.io https://storage.googleapis.com/istio-release/releases/{{< istio_full_version >}}/charts/` according to documentation [here](https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/install/helm/#helm-chart-release-repositories).

It seems that `helm repo add istio.io https://storage.googleapis.com/istio-release/releases/charts` work too but for older versions (up to 1.1.2). It is not yet documented but follow a more idiomatic versionning. An issue is open on istio : https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/15498

Answer (score 0):

The official helm chart is coming now!
https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/istio-official/gateway

Need to be careful [the comment in issue #31275](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/31275#issuecomment-917136870)

> Note: this is a 1.12 prerelease, so you need to pass --devel to all helm commands and should not run it in prod yet.

---

Because the chart is still in the `alpha` version, we need to pass `--devel` flag or specify a chart version to allow development versions.

Install steps:

```
helm repo add istio https://istio-release.storage.googleapis.com/charts
helm repo update

helm install --devel istio-ingressgateway istio/gateway
# or --version 1.12.0-alpha.1
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29798195)

Answer (score -1):

`helm repo add istio https://istio.io/charts` works. I found it in [this](https://github.com/istio/istio.github.io/pull/2616) PR.

Comment: this repo is currently behind latest 1.0.x version, just so that people reading this know...

Comment: this doesn't work, redirect is not working properly :/